# Как сделать ожидание сообщения в pytelegrambot (telebot)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно сделать ожидание сообщение от пользователя, то есть что-бы бот в бесконечном цикле при каждом перезапуске его ожидал сообщение и потом уже выполнял инструкции

Comment: Нужно – сделайте

Comment: А если серьёзно, покажите, что Вы уже пытались сделать. И скажите, что не получилось.

Comment: в интернете куча гайдов.
Я скажу лишь то, что нужно учить aiogram а не telebot!
telebot не поддерживается уже долгое количество времени, а последнее обновление aiogram произошло 3 дня назад; выбирать конечно вам, но aiogram лучше.

Comment: а разве бот по умолчанию не ожидает сообщения от пользователя? это ведь его основная функция, ждать пока не напишет пользователь и выполнить то что запрограммировано.

Comment: Telebot коммит 6 дней назад был